# https blocks all http content on my website?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I got a certificate and am currently trying to set up https.

However, I've got a problem : all the content from http source (not https) is blocked :

[blocked] The page at xxxxx ran insecure content from http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css

I saw many https site with pictures not hosted on the certified server. How can I allow this ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You'll need to provide configs to figure this one out.
Plus, it should be on serverfault, not stackoverflow as it is an admin rather than programming question

Comment: Request the content from a secure source: `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Answer (score 1):

Running HTTP content on a HTTPS page means that those insecure elements could potentially be used to interact with the secure page, thus defeating the point of having the security. This is why web browsers at the very least show warnings or block the content.

Overriding this behaviour is inadvisable if you value security on your website — you might as well not have the HTTPS at all. If your insecure content is compromised then your visitors are at risk.

You can probably edit your Chrome config files to stop the content from being blocked, but you shouldn't expect your visitors to do the same or even worse force them into it.